# What to do with this specific answer variation in the question?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers, answered-questions

The following question has an accepted answer and open bounty that will be awarded to it as soon as the delay is over.

[Bind Alt+Tab to a Logitech mouse button on Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/676775/367990)

Now the OP decided to edit his question to add the main parts of the (looong) answer to his question and sum it up and adapt it more strongly to his specific problem.

My usual behavior would be to edit the answer summary back out of the question and write it as community wiki answer instead. But I've left the OP a comment asking him to do this himself:

> Please do not forget to accept Velkan's answer if it solved your problem and to award it the bounty. Besides this, you should not edit your question to provide another solution, but write a new answer to the question yourself. If it's basically the same content that Velkan described in his post, you should consider just leaving it away or proposing a minor edit to his answer so that it fits all details of the question. Thanks for your participation here. [- 1st comment by me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676775/bind-alttab-to-a-logitech-mouse-button-on-kubuntu#comment983487_676775)

On which he reacted:

> @ByteCommander I can only award the bounty in 7 hours. The content is similar, but tailored to my specific situation. I thought it's not worth a self answer, since Velkan's gave me what I needed to know to come up with it and I'm accepting his anyway, so I just edited in what worked for me. If you insist on adding an answer I will, but I think it's more appropriate to keep it like this. [- 2nd comment by the OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676775/bind-alttab-to-a-logitech-mouse-button-on-kubuntu#comment983499_676775)

Now I still would stick to my original plan and convert the in-question answer to a real answer or to let the OP propose an edit to the original answer, but I don't want to do anything wrong and am not too sure here any more.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

You can comment that the OP can still award the bounty to any answer he likes. Self-answer does not mean that the bounty is awarded to the OP or to noone.

OP can still convert it to an answer, or you can do it for him. It does not really matter.

But keeping the answer in the question body is not good either way.